# Musescore - how to add general MIDI sound?

Tags: musescore

How do I add a [general MIDI instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_MIDI#Sound_effects), like bird tweet or guitar fret, to a Musecore score?

They aren't available in the instruments dialog, although all soundfonts support them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Add any instrument, e.g. piano
- Right click the staff and change the instrument name to Seashore (optional, this is just for easy reading later)
- View - Mixer (or F10) - change the sound dropdown to Seashore